# how add more item in actionbar (greendroid)

Tags: android, greendroid

how to add "more" item inside the actionbar(greendroid) ? How can i add three action menu item inside the actionbar. Anyone know how to add more and customize it .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modificate you style.xml

```
<style name="CusttomTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.GreenDroid.NoTitleBar">
.......
<item name="gdActionBarMaxItems">5</item>
.......
</style>
```

In that case you insert 5 item in the actionBar

Comment: thx guy , it works...really thx for help 
i have another question is how to customize the location of actionbarItems ...assume that i want to put ADD button in left side...

Comment: I think that it is not posible. And it doesn't follow the design of tipical Android Application.